# How to configure swagger UI of Restconf in Opendaylight

Tags: opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-restconf

Recently, I updated ODL project from Boron to Carbon.

Before when I open one API in the UI, those details defined in Yang model of each rpc wasn't showed in "Response Class". After the upgrade, all the details are showed up, which takes time to scroll down page.

I am just curious what's the related documentation or wiki that can be refereed to configure those stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all the details are showed up,

Isn't that great?! ;-)

> which takes time to scroll down page.

So you don't want that?

> I am just curious what's the related documentation or

The ODL project responsible for this is RESTCONF, part of NETCONF, see https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/NETCONF:Main and https://lists.opendaylight.org/mailman/listinfo/netconf-dev mailing list.

> to configure those stuff

There probably is no configuration to disable that.  But YOU could contribute such a feature?  Welcome to open source!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this
[OpenAPI 3.0 & OpenDaylight: A PANTHEON.tech Initiative](https://pantheon.tech/openapi-3-opendaylight-initiative/)
It is having the reference to open the swagger doc
http://localhost:8181/apidoc/explorer/index.html

Comment: I don't think the localhost hyperlink is useful in the majority of cases.